# 503 Service Unavailable error while accessing application service

Tags: servlets, netweaver

I have deployed two applications on a SAP NetWeaver system, one is a UI Application and one is an OSGi-based Web application exposing OData services.

The UI application is working fine and accessible but the Web application is not accessible.

I have verified that the application was deployed successfully and showing 'started' in the console, I also cross-checked through the internal `telnet` console of the application that all services are running, but while accessing the service in the browser or console, it's showing:

> 503 Service unavailable” for the Web application.

I tried to hit the URL through `curl` on that machine also but I'm getting the same result.

Is there any configuration required to make all the services accessible which are exposed by the application?

`web.xml` of application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"         
     version="2.5"         
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"> 
     
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.felix.http.proxy.ProxyListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.felix.http.proxy.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: `and showing 'started' in the console` what console? do you use WebIDE or BAS for deploying and developing?

Comment: SAP NetWeaver Administrator console and deploying through telnet

Comment: wow, what an old style! `The UI application is working fine and accessible but the Web application is not accessible` how did you confirm that UI is working fine if you wasn't able to test it via Web? In Eclipse?

Comment: both are different applications as I mentioned ,application-context for both applications is different. Able to access UI application URL in  browser